# Git: Better way to rebase 3rd branch onto 1st branch after 2nd branch merged

Tags: git, github, rebase

I have a branch with a big feature, that we can call A, and I created a branch B from last commit of A.

After some time I create a Pull Request in Github to merge B onto A. But because I do not want to wait, I create a branch C from B before it is merged.

```
[A] a---b---c---c1---c2
            \(A)
[B]           d---e---f
                      \(B)
[C]                     g---h
```

I committed on C, and meanwhile branch B has been merged onto A. So I want to cleanup my work and update my local A by pulling it from origin so I can have this situation:

```
[A] a---b---c---c1---c2---d---e---f
                                  \(A)
[C]                                 g---h
```

Now, here is my issue: I want C to be rebased onto A, but as B has been merged and removed (even locally because I pulled), so in order to rebase it I cannot do something like:

```
git rebase B C --onto A
```

But B does not exist anymore so when I git log, this is basically what I have:

```
[A]a---b---c---c1---c2

[C] d'---e'---f'---g---h


(This is what I have to do in order to rebase)

git rebase f' C --onto A
```

This works but I need to verify the hash of the last commit from B I can guess from C (here it is **f'**), and I may make mistakes here (and this looks ugly, like if all commits from B always have been on ).

Is there a better way to rebase C onto A after B has been merged ? Maybe I have to do something before pulling A?

If this is not clear enough please let me know (I do not ask questions often here! :) )

Answer (score 1):

Based on the exact first branch diagram you gave, you should only need to rebase the C branch on the A branch:

```
# from C branch
git rebase A
```

This will replay the commits `d` through `h` on top of the new base ending in commit `c2`, on the A branch.  Note that I would actually draw the resulting rebased C branch as this:

```
C: a -- b -- c -- c1 -- c2 -- d' -- e' -- f' -- g' -- h'
```

The prime marks (i.e. `d'` instead of `d`) indicate that commits `d'` through `h'` actually have been *rewritten*.  Note that replaying commits during a rebase means that the commits are made again, and are actually new commits.

Regarding what happens when you want to merge the rebased `C` back into `A`, let's draw the diagram this way:

```
A: a -- b -- c -- c1 -- c2
                          \
C:                         d' -- e' -- f' -- g' -- h'
```

After rebasing `C` on `A`, the former branch is now completely ahead of the latter `A` branch.  This means that if want to merge `C` back to `A`, you should simply be able to *fast-forward* the `A` branch, by directly applying commits `d'` though `f'` on top of `A`.

Comment: Thank you for your (very) quick answer!

In that case,  when I consider C as finished, what will happen when I want to merge C onto A, with all those commit from `d'` to `h'`? A will just have a to h' with no problem?